# smtp error on cpanel hosting when sending email

Tags: smtp, server, phpmailer, smtp-auth

i have php mailer where i have contact form in my webpage. There if someone fill the details like Name, Contact, Email, message etc and click on Send button, the below error throwing in screen, but i could able to receive mails but this error message comes every time sending message.

> SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220-astro.websitewelcome.com ESMTP Exim 4.85 #2
>   Thu, 30 Jul 2015 02:14:10 -0500 220-We do not authorize the use of
>   this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail. CLIENT
>   -> SMTP: EHLO dpaxis.com SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-astro.websitewelcome.com Hello dpaxis.com [192.185.13.234]
>   250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
>   250-STARTTLS 250 HELP CLIENT -> SMTP: AUTH LOGIN CLIENT -> SMTP:
>   aW5mb0BkcGF4aXMuY29t CLIENT -> SMTP: RGViYUA5ODE1UGVndQ== CLIENT ->
>   SMTP: MAIL FROM: SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 OK CLIENT -> SMTP: RCPT TO:
>   SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Accepted CLIENT -> SMTP: DATA SMTP -> FROM
>   SERVER:354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself CLIENT
>   -> SMTP: Date: Thu, 30 Jul 2015 02:14:10 -0500 CLIENT -> SMTP: Return-Path: CLIENT -> SMTP: To: dpaxis CLIENT -> SMTP: From: Test
>   Name CLIENT -> SMTP: Reply-To: Test Name CLIENT -> SMTP: Subject: TEST
>   CLIENT -> SMTP: Message-ID:
>   <7d74be28b53bdecd9f9eb5c06e9cd7ea@dpaxis.com> CLIENT -> SMTP:
>   X-Priority: 3 CLIENT -> SMTP: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.6
>   (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/) CLIENT -> SMTP:
>   MIME-Version: 1.0 CLIENT -> SMTP: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
>   CLIENT -> SMTP: boundary="b1_7d74be28b53bdecd9f9eb5c06e9cd7ea" CLIENT
>   -> SMTP: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit CLIENT -> SMTP: CLIENT -> SMTP: --b1_7d74be28b53bdecd9f9eb5c06e9cd7ea CLIENT -> SMTP:
>   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1 CLIENT -> SMTP:
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit CLIENT -> SMTP: CLIENT -> SMTP: Name:
>   Test Name Email: test@gmail.com Phone: 787848788748 Service: PHP /
>   MySQL Message: TEST This Form was submitted from:
>   http://dpaxis.com/dpaxisuc/coming-soon.html CLIENT -> SMTP: CLIENT ->
>   SMTP: CLIENT -> SMTP: --b1_7d74be28b53bdecd9f9eb5c06e9cd7ea CLIENT ->
>   SMTP: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 CLIENT -> SMTP:
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit CLIENT -> SMTP: CLIENT -> SMTP: Name:
>   Test Name

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error message, it's just debug output. Disable it by setting `$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;`.

PHPMailer 5.2.6 is very old and buggy. [Get the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and base your code on one of the examples you'll find on there too.

Also, please learn how to format your question so that it's actually readable.

Comment: Thanks a ton, i have fixed.